# Migrating from ARM 5 to ARM 6 Compiler: Use of undeclared identifier '__Vectors'

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation, arm, clang

Currently migrating a large C-language project from ARM 5 to ARM 6 compiler within Keil uVision. One of the files is a third-party file. The one error that has me stumped is `error: use of undeclared identifier '__Vectors'`. In the same file, there are some `#define` directives for various compilers, and for the Keil case, it just has

```
#elif (defined __CC_ARM)
  extern unsigned char __Vectors
```

which works fine for ARM 5. ARM 6 now is based on clang, so I'm wondering if that's the problem, and if so, what the new `__Vectors` keyword should be defined as.

I am using the latest (Version 5.2.0) of CMSIS and the latest version of my particular STM device support.

Comment: Also possibly related, what does the ARM 6 compiler 'define' itself as? I can't imagine that it would still be `__CC_ARM` like ARM 5 simply due to the many incompatibilities between 5 and 6...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the third-party file was that it did not have the necessary `#define` case for the ARM 6 compiler, which is not the same as ARM 5's `#elif (defined __CC_ARM)`.

The missing lines were:

```
#elif defined (__ARMCC_VERSION) && (__ARMCC_VERSION >= 6010050)
     extern unsigned char __Vectors;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a reference to the interrupt vector table.

It's not trying to "define a keyword"; it's declaring an external variable. The variable generally comes from the linker script so you need to dig there.

If the code doesn't *use* the variable, you can of course remove it, but perhaps it's manipulating the interrupt vector table in some manner and thus needs to access it.